# How can I get more shields?

Tags: polybius

In Pure and Classic mode, you get shields at the end of each level. I believe that you always get 2, but I could be wrong.

Is there any other way to get shields, like *during* a level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems besides at the end of levels (in only Pure and Classic like you said), there are opportunities to pickup (immunity) shields mid-level [as quoted here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-05-12-polybius-review): (Bold emphasis mine)

> Somewhere along the line, **pickups, in the form of brightly coloured
>   pills**, come into play too, adding to your weapons and boosting your
>   speed and point-scoring capacity even further. **At times, you can gain
>   a shield of invulnerability for a few moments**, which lets you race
>   through all oncoming enemies and any immovable parts of the landscape
>   with impunity.

Comment: Oh, that explains why I didn't die when I crashed through a million things one time. There's so much going on, it's really difficult to keep up, hah. The shields I was asking about were the ones that essentially act as "extra lives", but this works, too.

Comment: Yeah I just watched a little clip and it's a lot just coming at you. I wasn't able to find anything about those end of level shields/lives though. The closest thing was that immunity one.